# ¿Cuál es el antónimo de mentir?

Tags: verbos, antónimos

¿Existe en el idioma español?

Se suele "decir la verdad", pero, ¿se cuenta con algún verbo (simple, y no compuesto), que pueda suplir dicha expresión?

Comment: Llevo un rato pensándolo y diría que no hay ningún verbo que signifique eso por sí mismo. "Decir la verdad" es la expresión común.

Comment: What about confesar?

Answer (score 10):

Después de un rato dándole vueltas, no he podido encontrar el antónimo buscado ni en el español actual ni en diccionarios anteriores. Tampoco encuentro ni en inglés, francés o italiano un verbo que simplemente signifique "decir la verdad". Pero el caso es que ni siquiera parece haberlo en latín. Lo más que encuentro son aproximaciones:

- [Afirmar](https://dle.rae.es/afirmar).
- [Aseverar](https://dle.rae.es/aseverar).
- [Certificar](https://dle.rae.es/certificar).
- [Corroborar](https://dle.rae.es/corroborar).
- [Sincerar](https://dle.rae.es/sincerar).
- ...

Lo más cercano que he encontrado podría ser *confesar*:

> **[confesar](https://dle.rae.es/confesar)**
>
> Del lat. mediev. *confessare*, y este der. del lat. *confessus* 'confeso'.
>
> 1. tr. Dicho de una persona: Expresar voluntariamente sus actos, ideas o sentimientos verdaderos. U. t. c. prnl.

La pega es que ni estos ni ningún otro verbo de significado similar son intransitivos, como lo es el verbo *mentir*. Y además todos ellos tienen alguna particularidad en su significado que hace que no sean antónimos exactos.

Y si los anteriores verbos no son lo suficientemente válidos como antónimo de *mentir*, propongo la creación de un nuevo verbo:

> **veritar**
>
> Del latín *veritas*
>
> 1. intr. Decir o manifestar lo que se sabe, cree o piensa.

Comment: el concepto de mentir fue necesario una vez demonstrado que afirmaciones no siempre son la verdad.  Todavía entro en discusiones si mentir implica intencionalidad de mentir o no.  Yo pienso que crear un verbo para indicar lo que debería ser lo natural en comunicación oral, aunque pueda ser necesario, es triste.  Se me ocurren otras acciones sin antónimo: brincar, correr, saltar...

Comment: @David obviamente, lo de crear un verbo no es más que una pequeña broma lingüística por mi parte, aunque es verdad que tiene un punto triste...

Comment: Vengo a comentar que en México, cuando se trata de enfatizar la verdad de algo que suene increíble, es común decir "de veritas" y pensaba yo que era una creación regional, ya veo que tiene fundación en el latín.

Comment: @celerno, también podría ser un diminutivo de "de veras" (de verdad)(http://dle.rae.es/?id=baviEMz).

Answer (score 7):

Yo utilizaría la forma reflexiva del verbo *sincerar*:

> #### [**sincerarse**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XwnJ9KX)
>
> ...
> 2. prnl. Hablar sinceramente con alguien, especialmente contándole algo que se mantenía oculto.

P.S. Incluso así, no es un antónimo exacto de mentir ni es un verbo simple (verbo reflexivo) pero puede valer dependiendo de la ocasión.

Answer (score 1):

Existen algunas propuestas, como:

**Ortologar**. 
Según [¿CUÁL ES EL ANTÓNIMO DE MENTIR? - por Marco Aurelio Denegri.](http://profesor-sucari.blogspot.com/2015/06/cual-es-el-antonimo-de-mentir-por-marco.html)

> Seguín propuso, a fin  de subsanar la falta, el verbo ortologar, compuesto de orto-, forma prefija del griego orthós, recto, derecho, correcto, y –logo, forma  sufija del griego lógos, palabra, y sufijo-ar, formante del infinitivo verbal. Ortologar significa, pues, hablar verazmente, decir la pura verdad, expresarse de tal modo que haya conformidad entre lo que se dice y lo que se siente o se piensa.

**Verasear**

Comment: Bienvenido a Spanish.SE! Buena respuesta, pero mejoraría si la editaras para dejar claro que esas palabras no existen en el idioma español, y añaderas algún link a las propuestas. ¿Quién las ha propuesto?

Comment: Gran contribución Patrick. Bienvenido. He hecho un edit para "ortologar". Podrías usarlo de ejemplo para añadir alguna similar para "verasear". También habría que resaltar que (por lo menos según se entiende del artículo enlazado para Ortologar) estos términos no están admitidos por la RAE. Ortologar tiene su mérito, pero no está admitido.

Answer (score 1):

Algo cercano:

> #### [testificar](https://dle.rae.es/testificar).
>
> `Del lat. testificāri.`
>
> ...
>
> 3. tr. Declarar, explicar y denotar con seguridad y verdad algo, en lo físico y en lo moral.

Answer (score 1):

En la práctica, lo opuesto de *mentir* es **ser honesto** o **decir la verdad**.  Veamos un ejemplo.

Gabi dice

> Mi hijo, ¿será que me estás mintiendo?

Pero su espos@, que suele expresarse en términos más positivos, lo hace de esta forma:

> Mi hijo, sé honesto, por favor.  Dime qué pasó de verdad.

O bien:

> Mi hijo, dime la verdad, por favor.  ¿Qué pasó?

Answer (score 0):

No parece haber un verbo simple nítidamente establecido en oposición a `mentir` (engañar a sabiendas)

Votaría por uno (también propuesto por @Charlie), que es

> aseverar

Es el que más me gusta (quizás por su resonancia sonora con verdad) pero cuya etimología parece estar ligada a [fuerte, firme, seguro](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?aseverar)

Nótese que en el (prolífico) idioma inglés [tampoco existe un antónimo simple opuesto para el verbo "(to) lie" (*mentir*)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/161550/antonym-for-lying/161580#161580)
por lo que también como en el castellano, se usan frases verbales `to tell the truth`

Para nosotros, comunmente —al menos en Argentina, y probablemente en otras regiones— para ***expresar la garantía de una voluntad sincera de decir las cosas tal cual se las entiende, percibe o siente***, se estila usar:

> "a decir verdad" / " "en verdad" / "sinceramente", "honestamente (hablando)"

PD 1: En Tucumán (provincia Argentina del Noroeste), hay una modalidad curiosa, que muy probablemente sea una particularidad regional, que consiste en calificar algo como:

> *posta*

Se usa exactamente como adjetivo,sinónimo de verdadero, para significar garantía `"(tal cómo [te] lo digo)"

Por ejemplo:

> Ayer a la tarde he visto cuatro corzuelas en el camino"
>
> —¿posta?
>
> ¡posta!

En general se usan para ratificar algo destacable o inverosimil. Tengo un sobrino, especialmente alto, para quien le es común recibir comentarios admirativo de su altura dentro de un intermcambio típico cuyo desarrollo alguna vez me refirió:

> —¿cuánto medís?
>
> "dos metros"
>
> —¿posta?
>
> *"¡posta!"* (equivalente vernáculo a "no te miento")

Comment: Mi inclusión de formas locales que conozco áan en la dirección de señalar el relativo vacío de un término verbal simple que sea utilizado.

Comment: Muchas veces me llamó la atención una muletilla comun {en Arg) con las que algunas personas anteceden una respuesta, diciendo `no te qurero mentir... (pero me parece tal cosa)`

Answer (score -1):

Solo tiene antónimo gramatical: desmentir. Se supone que hablar debe incluir la manifestación de la verdad al menos la que el hablante conoce. La verdad... No se dice, no se construye, como la mentira, solo de revela. No es una acción en sí misma, la acción es decirla, revelarla o desvelarla, confesarla una vez conocida.

Answer (score -1):

¿Por qué mientes? Cuestiona que lo qu estamos escuchando es mentira o lo parece. 
Como cuestionamos o preguntamos que lo que escuchamos es verdad o lo parece.
¿Por qué NO mientes? ¡Acaso así!, asumiendo que NO mentir es lo contrario de mentir ya que éste verbo no tiene un antónimo definido.

Comment: No se trata tanto de cuestionamos o preguntamos que lo que escuchamos es verdad. Puedes pedirle a alguien que diga la verdad: "sincérate:. La cosa es encontrar un verbo mejor que la expresión "dí la verdad". Decir simplemente que no hay un antónimo definido, sin aportar más, convierte a esta contribución en un comentario, y no una respuesta. Decir que no existe tal verbo o antónimo es legítimo, pero tendrás que aportar alguna referencia lo valide.

Answer (score -1):

La compone: Mente y Urdir.

Puede significar: subordinar con la mente.

"para mentir no se necesita decir palabra alguna" 
 https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mentira

Y que puede ser el antonimo de la mente?

Verificar antonimo de falsificar.

Confesar:  Con-Fateri:  Junto,todo-Hablar,admitir.

Comment: -1. Entiendo que esta es tu primera contribución, pero es muy poco clara. Aparte, no creo que ni Verificar ni Confesar sean antónimos directos de "mentir" (que signifiquen por si mismos "decir la verdad", que es lo que se pide en la pregunta". No sé si verificar es el antónimo de falsificar como afirmas. Para mi es sinónimo de "comprobar". Confesar podría ser uno bueno, aunque tiene cierta connotación de "obligado por la fuerza". Te animo a mejorar un poco esta contribución, tal vez añadiendo entradas al DRAE como la de confesar: https://dle.rae.es/confesar?m=form y revertiré mi voto negativo